# Internal Android phone storage disappeared

Tags: storage

My Motorola G2 has an 8 gigabyte internal storage but some of it has vanished!

In settings/ storage and USB, here is what it shows:

[image: A]

Out of my 8GB storage, 3.15 is used by Android OS so I have 4.85GB of space left. I also have and SD card which contains all my photos, music, videos and some apps, and the "Other" folder.

On the internal storage section

[image: A]

I have used 1.7GB of space in apps and 1.92MB of cached data which doesn't add up the the 4.80GB that it has said I have used out of the 4.85GB which I have. So where has the 3.1GB of memory gone?

I would appreciate any help, Thanks

Comment: Your SD card is configured as internal (adopted) storage but it doesn't seem to be used as it should... Press the 3 dot overflow menu and see if you can migrate data to SD card.

Comment: Download any file explorer and see the memory usage of different folders. I guess you have some downloads or other files in phone storage.

Comment: I have the same issue with several Moto X phones, and a Samsung tablet.  The Samsung tablet takes longer to gobble up space, but the Mot X phones, which are limited to 16gb, tend to do it within several months.  The only solution I have found to work, temporarily, is to factory reset.   Using file explorers is futile, as they cannot see the lost space.